# How to write regular expression for all text after ":"

Tags: python, regex

I need to filter the sentence and select only few terms from the whole sentence

For example, I have sample text:

```
ID: a9000006        
NSF Org     : DMI
Total Amt.  : $225024

Abstract    :This SBIR proposal is aimed at (1) the synthesis of new ferroelectric liquid crystals with ultra-high polarization,                    
             chemical stability and low viscosity
```

```py
token = re.compile('a90[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]| [$][\d]+ |')
re.findall(token, filetext)
```

I get `'a9000006','$225024'`, but I do not know how to write regex for three upper case letter right after `"NSF Org:"` which is `"DMI"` and all text after `"Abstract:"`

Comment: `[^:]+` will grab everything that isn't a colon.

Comment: A simple split with a limit will be much more efficient than regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a single regex which will match each of those 4 fields with explicit checks on each, then use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/DNLI9O/1): `:\s?(a90[\d]+|[$][\d]+|[A-Z]{3}|.*$)`

```
>>> token = re.compile(r':\s?(a90[\d]+|[$][\d]+|[A-Z]{3}|.*$)', re.DOTALL)  # flag needed
>>> re.findall(token, filetext)
['a9000006', 'DMI', '$225024', 'This SBIR proposal is aimed at (1) the synthesis of new ferroelectric liquid crystals wi
th ultra-high polarization,                    \n             chemical stability and low viscosity']
>>>
```

However, since you're searching for all at the same time, would be better to use one which matches all 4 together and generically, such as the one in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54740540/1431750).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, could you tell me what should I write regex if I just want "DMI" after "NSF Org:"?

Comment: That part in the regex is `[A-Z]{3}`. If you want the whole regex for just that part, then split the one I've given along the `|` (optional match conditions, which are rules matching each of the 4 fields). To match only 'DMI', use: `r':\s([A-Z]{3})'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i use (r'NSF Org\s*:\s*(.*)') and it works as well

Answer (score -1):

This must do the job.

```
: .*
```

You can check this here.
[check](https://regexr.com/48i4k)

Comment: I think that does not match what the OP is looking for https://regex101.com/r/mXoZQs/1

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: But now it matches the colon and the following space as well.